# SQL Insert top n names from table A to a table B row, with n names in row

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `A(id integer,name varchar(10))` and a table `B(id integer,name1 varchar(10),name2 varchar(10), name3 varchar(10))`

I want the top 3 names of table A to get inserted into the a table B row.
for example, if i have:

```
table A
id    name
1     ed
2     edd
3     eddd
4     mike
```

i want this:

```
table B
id    name1    name2    name3
1     ed       edd      eddd
```

a normal `order by id` of table A is fine.

Comment: What makes names "top 3"  if  rule is: `don't pay attention on order by` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze sorry i meant: it doesnt matter how you order it...that's not part of my question...a normal `order by id` is fine in your answer :) ..gonna edit my question, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pivot using conditional aggregation and insert:

```
insert into b (name1, name2, name3)
    select max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end),
           max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end),
           max(case when seqnum = 3 then name end)
    from (select a.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
          from a
          order by id
          limit 3
         ) a;
```

This assumes that `id` is a serial column.  If not, just throw in `min(id)` as the first column being selected and inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as ( -- get first 3 names into single array
  select array_agg(name) as first_3_names
  from table_a
  order by id limit 3)
insert into table_b (name1, name2, name3) -- then insert array's elements into the appropriate columns
select first_3_names[1], first_3_names[2], first_3_names[3] from t;
```